# Rounded Corners Image Change on Hover

Tags: css, html

I created a rounded box/button and sliced its first corner, the middle bar (which repeats horizontally to adjust the width of the button text/content) and the last corner and used following markup:

```
<div id="left-corner"></div>
<div id="middle-bar">About Us</div>
<div id="right-corner"></div>
```

These divs have corresponding images from CSS and are floated left. Those three divs create a single rounded button wiht text **About Us** which is fine.

**Problem:**

I have also created similar three slices of hover images but I wonder how to apply hover to those buttons because if I use `:hover` with these hovered slices, then even hovering on corner images also creates hovering effect. One alternative is to use **fixed width** buttons and slice buttons completely but I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you wrap those three divs in another div? Like:

```
<div id="button_wrapper">
    <div id="left-corner"></div>
    <div id="middle-bar">About Us</div>
    <div id="right-corner"></div>
</div>
```

You could then implement hover changes on the wrapping div:

```
#button_wrapper:hover #left-corner {}
#button_wrapper:hover #middle-bar {}
#button_wrapper:hover #right-corner {}
```

Alternatively, have you considered using `border-radius`. You won't get any love from IE, but it degrades nicely and is [ridiculously easy to implement](http://border-radius.com/):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with `<a>` element (use spans instead of divs if you care about semantic HTML).

```
<a href="#" class="button">
   <div id="left-corner"></div>
   <div id="middle-bar">About Us</div>
   <div id="right-corner"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button:hover #left-corner { /* something here */ }
.button:hover #middle-bar{ /* something here */ }
.button:hover #right-corner { /* something here */ }
```

Edit:

Because :hover pseudo selector can be only used on `<a>` element on IE6, that's why we must use it.